# javascript regex to find multiple strings in a line preceded by a key:

Tags: javascript, regex, yaml

How can I match all the strings, in any order, but only if preceded by certain key?

example I want to match article and legal no matter the order as long as they are preceded by tags:

```
---
author: Karen the Trollmaster
tags: noise, legal, irrelevant, article
keywords: pff, nobody, likes, "a Karen", "not this", article // < don't match this one
---
```

What I have so far is

```
(?<=(tags: ))(article)|(legal)
```

but this isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in two steps, first isolate the `tags:` line, then use `match()` to find all keywords with an alternation regex.

```js
var input = `---
author: Karen the Trollmaster
tags: noise, legal, irrelevant, article
keywords: pff, nobody, likes, "a Karen", "not this", article // < don't match this one
---`;
var keywords = ["article", "legal"];
var regexp = new RegExp("\\b(" + keywords.join("|") + ")\\b", "g");
var matches = input.match(/\btags:.*?(?=\n|$)/)[0].match(regexp);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Thank you, seems nice. Anyway for now I only need REGEX compatible with js

Comment: The above code snippet should be 100% compatible with any version of JavaScript.  Not sure what your comment is supposed to mean here.

Comment: Exactly, you posted a javascript snippet, in the software where I will use it I can't edit the code. There is just a form where I'm just allowed to input a REGEX string. everything else will be sanitized, or the form will be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the pattern as:

```
(?<=tags: .*)\b(?:article|legal)\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert to the left from the current position

  - `tags: .*` Match `tags:`  and 0+ times any
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `\b(?:article|legal)\b` Match either article or legal between word boundaries

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2hezu8/1)

Note that you can omit the capture groups for a match only

```js
const regex = /(?<=tags: .*)\b(?:article|legal)\b/gm;
const str = `---
author: Karen the Trollmaster
tags: noise, legal, irrelevant, article
keywords: pff, nobody, likes, "a Karen", "not this", article // < don't match this one
---`;

console.log(str.match(regex));
```

If both words should be present, you can make use of lookarounds to match either of the words and assert the other word to be present on the left or the right side

```
(?<=tags: .*)(?:\blegal\b(?=.*\barticle\b)|\barticle\b(?=.*\blegal\b)|(?<=.*\barticle\b.*)\blegal\b|(?<=.*\blegal\b.*)\barticle\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gcd4RV/1)

Comment: This one is looking nice, however is there a way to match only if BOTH tags are present?

Comment: @aalvarado Yes, but then for a match only you would have to assert to both the left and the right and the pattern would be longer, see https://regex101.com/r/cao82g/1